# Detect text node collapse?

Tags: html

`<p>This is example:</p> <p>test</p>`, the text node with spaces between `</p>` and `<p>` IS collapsed (doesn't show).

`<b>This</b> <em>is</em> an example`, the text node with space between `</b>` and `<em>` IS NOT collapsed (does show a white space).

Is there a way to determine which case a text node belong to with javascript?

Comment: Spaces between two blocks will be "collapsed. Spaces between two inline-blocks or inlines will be collapsed into one. Spaces in certain elements like `pre` will not be collapsed.

Comment: What about space nodes in an element without previousSibling or nextSibling? What about CSS "white-space" property? Is there an official document about the standard of the wrapping behavior?

Comment: Here's the link to the official specification of handling white spaces in HTML[5]: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space-rules If a value for the `white-space` property is not provided, `normal` would be assumed.